# Substring not working on ToDouble - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using ASP.NET with VB.NET.

This is my code

```
Dim Total As Double
Total = Convert.ToDouble(lblTotal.Text.Substring(4, 20))
```

The value of lblTotal is

> ABC20.00

I just want to trim the value to give me the 20.00 and convert it ToDouble

End Result Must be

> 20.00

C# code will also help me undertand what needs to happen and why I am getting the error messsage

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

Comment: When you get an exception, read the documentation of the method you're calling to see whether that explains it. In this case, it really does...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
Total = Convert.ToDouble(lblTotal.Text.Substring(4))
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx

EDIT - as per comment:

The OP used in his example code 4 as starting index but the sample data would have to use 3 as starting index to achieve the result...

Comment: The problem is......the value can also be 2000.00 or 200000.00, I need to remove the first 3 values ABC

Comment: that is exactly what my code does - it take ALL characters AFTER the first 3 characters... check out the link in my answer...

Comment: Thanks, got it now! Had a small mistake when I tested.

Comment: Shouldn't that be .Substring(3)?

Comment: I just took the 4 from the OPs code... and he seems happy... so not sure, it would seem that you are right, but from his code and reaction it seems that this was what he asked for...

Comment: @Yahia: It might be that he found out himself that it should be 3, and just didn't bother to tell here. As reference for others, this should be pointed out in your answer.

Comment: added a note regarding 3 versus 4 :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's not Double's fault but yours.
Just use `.Substring(3)` only.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the entire remainder of the string, use the overload of [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) that only takes a `startIndex` parameter, and no `length` parameter:

```
Convert.ToDouble(lblTotal.Text.Substring(4))
```

If you want to take some limited amount of the remainder of the string, you must ensure the `length` you ask for is less than or equal to the number of characters available:

```
Convert.ToDouble(lblTotal.Text.Substring(4, Math.Max(20,lblTotal.Text.Length-3)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The **first** parameter to `Substring()` is the **startindex**. This tells the method where in the string to start taking the new string.

The **second** parameter is the **length** of the string to be taken.

You have specified 4, 20 --> which says that you want to start from 0 and take the next 20 characters.

But your string is only 8 characters long. This is why you're getting the message:

*Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length*

So, use:

```
lblTotal.Text.Substring(3, lblTotal.Text.Length - 3)
```

Note that Substring() is overloaded. Since you want to take the entire string after 'ABC', you can use the other signature that only takes the starting index:

```
Total = Convert.ToDouble(lblTotal.Text.Substring(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lblTotal.Text.Substring(4, lblTotal.text.length - 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is a little bit off; in your code you are specifying the length of the substring as 20 characters long when in reality your `string.length` is only 8 characters.

```
(lblTotal.Text.Substring(4, 20)) ' the 20th index does not exist.
```

Rather you should use:

```
Convert.ToDouble(lblTotal.Text.Substring(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: The second parameter of SubString is number of characters to get, starting on the index position ( and the first parameter is index, wich is 0 base).

```
Dim Total As Double
Total = Convert.ToDouble(lblTotal.Text.Substring(3))
```

Note that since index is 0 based, your start index must be 3:

```
Index:        01234567
String value: ABC20.00
```

When only using the start index (remove the length parameter), it will return from the start index and the rest of the string (no matter how long it is).